# On Adobe AIR mobile application, Will IOS load external swf with actionscript at all?

Tags: ios, air, adobe, flash

I have tons of old swf files that contains assets and needs to be shown in AIR app for IOS. Some of assets contains simple actionscript code mostly stop(). I really do not care if the actionscript inside the swf gets executed or not. The question is - If I will try to load the swf that contains actionscript, will it load?

I mean, I can see that on Ad-Hoc version it loads, but will it load when I publish to the appstore?

Comment: I didn't know this, but it is possible to do that with assets (things that don't have code that needs to be executed). I always thought Apple didn't want you to **load** byte code at run time, but it seems to be they don't want you to **execute** byte code *that was loaded* at run time. Check the 2nd to last bullet point on this [blog post](http://www.flashrealtime.com/compiling-big-air-swf-to-ios/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If something works on Ad-Hoc, it will surely work on App Store.** The only potential problem is Apple review during which they can decide that your app is not suitable for the App Store.